# Unable to sign in to Google account in Android Studio

Tags: 16.04, android-studio

I am using android studio 2.2.3 in Ubuntu 16.04. When I click on Sign in to my Google account from Android studio, It says "Please Sign in via the opened browser". When I navigate to browser there no tab opened for signing into google account.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like there are two Chrome windows open.

Comment: In Other one `youtube` is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem is solved after I changed the default browser to `Firefox`. Previously default browser was `Google chrome`. It's weird tho. :)

**For changing default Browser**

`System Settings` > `System` > `Details` > `Default Applications`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you don't open android studio as a root user.
Also if you are cloning a git project do not clone via root user.

Answer (score 2):

**For users who have Android Studio 3.1**

Go to `File-> Settings-> Tools-> Web Browsers`

Here you can find the `Default Browser` where `System default`is default selected when installing Android Studio 3.1.

In my case I solved the problem by changing `System default` to `First listed`.

As ubuntu no longer supports `Google Chrome` you can uncheck the chrome so that android studio will automatically select `Firefox` or the browser listed below it.